# ioncube not load after upgrading to php 5.4

Tags: php, ioncube

i am afraid that i broke somthing in my vps :/ i hope you can help me.

i am on ubuntu-12.04-x86.
and i moved to new vps so i tryied to upgrade the php to the news version from 5.3 to 5.4.
anyway after installing i get this messages:

```
fild loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so /usr/php5/20090625+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: undefined synbol: php_body_wri 
php 5.4.8-1~presise+1 (cli) (built(oct 29 2012)
```

i need to mention that the server is working and php also working but when i do phpinfo
there is **no**

> "with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.0.14, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by
>   ionCube Ltd."

which was before :/
i installed with this guide:http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/03/how-to-upgrade-install-php-540-under.html

i need to worry?

**edit**
ok so  think i found the solution inspired by  Devator answer i downloaded the last ioncube from their website in zip file. in this zip file i found the file `ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so` than i uploaded the file to the folder where i saw php looking for the 5.3 version eg:`"/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/"`, than i go to my php.ini file and put the line but it didnt work so i saw file `00-ioncube-loader-5.3.ini` in  `conf.d folder` in there i saw the line `zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so` i edited to `zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so` restart apache and now i saw the line where php info

```
'This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by ionCube Ltd.'
```

sorry for bad english :/
problem solved i think so

Comment: Did you add `zend_extension = /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so` to your php.ini or is it present?

Comment: i tryied now to add it, and restart the server. not help tnx

Comment: i searched and there is no file ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so there is only: ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so ioncube_loader_lin_5.1.so

Comment: @Devator Since that appears to be the answer, you should probably post it as such.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Done, didn't want to mess up the answers if it didn't was the answer. Felt like it should be a comment, but as it's the answer I made an.. answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add `zend_extension = /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so` to your php.ini or is it present?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has the same case:
After checking Devator's solution, be sure that php is compiled with the following two flags:
*--disable-maintainer-zts*
*--disable-safe-mode*
or rather that these flags are NOT present:
*--enable-maintainer-zts*
*--enable-safe-mode*
If running WHM, these can be written in the Raw Opts file documented here:
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Raw+Opts

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue after upgrading to PHP 5.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 following this tutorial: http://phpave.com/upgrade-php-5-3-php-5-5-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

You just need to run the following after the instructions above.

```
dpkg-reconfigure php5-ioncube-loader
```